# Sharepoint compatibility issue on Windows 8.1 IE11 browser

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint 2010 website (works fine on IE8) which has many issues when opened in Windows 8.1 IE11 browser.I am able to check-out a file, but unable to check-in or Discard Check-out files.

Could you please advice if there is a fix for this? Below are my system versions,

```
Windows 8.1 Enterprise
IE11 (v11.0.9600.16384)  , Update version: RTM(KB2841134)
```

Also, while debugging the scripts on IE11, I have observed that the Micrsosoft Sharepoint javascript function "StsOpenEnsureEx"  does not work properly.

Do we have any patches or upgrades on sharepoint for this fix ?

(I have tried the "compatibility view settings" on IE11 browser , but the still the issues exist)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just wondering, if http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ - a better place for such a question.

Comment: The modern browsers are not officially supported by Sharepoint 2007/2010. So some features couldn't work properly because could be based on not compatible technology.
When you say "unable to check-in", you mean in doing what exactly? It's possible that you cannot do it using the buttons in the ribbon, but if you use the dropdown action menu from the item it should work.